# Using Underscore.js to filter and merge json

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I have a use case where I need to use underscore.js to filter a JSON. For example

```
{"test":{
{ key: 1,country:USA,product:A,price:200}
{key: 1,country:USA,product:B,price:200}
{key: 1,country:UK,product:B,price:300}
}
}
```

I have multiple dimensions for same key. I need to get the output as follows when i filter USA

```
{"test":{
{ key: 1,country:USA,price:400}
}
}
```

and when I filter for product B

```
{"test":{
{ key: 1,product:B,price:500}
}
}
```

I'd like to implement this using underscore.js as I believe it is fast compared to pure JS options.

Comment: You can filter by either `country` or `product` right? Or can you do both simultaneously?

Comment: Hi Vivek, I can filter by product or country at a time. The idea is to get aggregated prices for each dimension after filtering. Thanks.

Comment: What is "a JSON", and what does JSON have to do with your problem, which appears to be about a plain old JavaScript object?

Comment: *I'd like to implement this using underscore.js as I believe it is fast compared to pure JS options.* Why would you believe that? Underscore is just a library implemented in "pure JS", no magic there.

Comment: If you want to aggregate after filtering, please add that requirement to your question, instead of putting it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to use underscore _.filter to apply searching with your criteria like product or country.

Then do an aggregation based on result from filter by simply use _.each function.

Finally, you can manipulate your result in _.map function.

I posted jsfiddle link here, it might help you

```
jsfiddle.net/zusquang/39os1854/
```

I'm doing hope this help.

Comment: Hi Quang, thanks for fiddle! This is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Could you do a vote if my answer is useful? @NandakumarUdayakumar

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a typo and test contains an array of objects:

```
var filtered = JSON.parse(jsonString).test.filter(function(item) { return item.country == 'USA' });
var total = 0;

filtered.forEach(function(item) {
    total += item.price
});
```

Don't worry about speed, this would be a micro-optimization, which is not recommended.